# Non-blocking mlock()

Tags: c++, c, linux, file-io

Is there such a thing as non-blocking mlock()? Under heavy traffic, I don't want my threads block waiting for I/O. I'd rather just tell the Linux kernel what region I need from a mmap()'d file using mlock() and then get notified when the pages has been fetched. (As far as I know, the standard mlock() call is blocking.)

Answer (score 2):

The `mlock` interface does not seem to have any built-in functionality like what you want, so I think the only way to achieve it is to use a separate thread to perform the `mlock` and have that thread notify you (via a condition variable, semaphore, or other mechanism) when the `mlock` has returned. Obviously this is going to incur some overhead, but if your goal is to get realtime latency guarantees rather than improving overall runtime/average latency, it's still an obvious win.

Of course it's hard to make any realtime assumptions unless you use `mlockall` since your code could get swapped out. So it might make more sense to use `mlockall` and POSIX AIO (or a similar but cleaner-API system implemented yourself in terms of threads) to do reads rather than using `mmap`. Then you have a hard guarantee that, once your data is fetched, it can't be swapped out.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you want a combination of `madvise()` or `posix_madvise()` and `mincore()`.

You would use a `madvise` call to ask the kernel for `MADV_WILLNEED`. Then you would have to poll using `mincore` to check if the pages had been read into memory.

If the system is under heavy memory load it is possible for the pages to never be read in by the `madvise` call, so you would need a timeout and a fallback to a blocking read mode.

Comment: +1 I'd even say `madvise` alone is the best way to go, all without `mincore`. Giving the OS a few millis of a head start to load pages should work most of the time, and if it doesn't do it, you're at loss anyway (can just as well page fault then, same effect really). Only have to remember to reset pages to `MADV_NORMAL` afterwards, or after some time your complete address space will be set to "will need", and it becomes useless.

Comment: @Damon: But this is in reference to mlock which is sort of the ultimate "will need". Also, I am fairly sure that once the page is loaded into RAM the Linux kernel ignores/drops the WILLNEED flag. I am not sure if this is true of all POSIX systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you mmap() a file, then you treat the file as memory, the VM pages in/out file blocks depending on your usage, which may benefit from read ahead.

There are various ways to do non-blocking I/O (asyncio, poll, select, epoll) but mlock() is about holding a memory region in RAM, not allowing it to be paged out to the swap partition; though under severe memory pressure the kernel may not honour that.

Most likely, mmap(2) will suffice as if you are using memory pages, they will not be selected for page out, but kept in memory anyway, so consider if this question is premature optomisation, the kernel tries hard to provide (by default) good performance.

Comment: mlock'd memory will never go to swap. The machine will crash first. That is one reason it is limited in how much a user account can mlock.

Comment: According to LWN.net article recently that is not quite true, if memory pressure is sufficiently high, the kernel may disregard the "request" although there is a way to mlock which guarantees a locked region will never be selected no matter how desperate the kernel gets that requires non-default calls.

Comment: Do you mean that mlock can fail? Yes it can. But if it succeeds it will not swap it.

Comment: No I mean it can appear to succeed but the OS can still evict the pages if memory pressure is sufficiently high, unless particular options are chosen.  Regard it as soft mlocking v a hard mlock which truly ties up memory resources no matter what.

Comment: Um. Evidence? Because mlock is guaranteed to not do that and I have never seen it. I could see some unusual situation causing it. A virtual host might swap out a locked guest. Programmers can also screw up. If you, or free, munmap's and then maps more without using MCL_FUTURE then that new memory will not be locked.

Comment: Read the info on LWN about mlock, discussing the real Linux implementation using a search engine.  You'll find what I said was correct in 2014

Comment: Fraid I can't find it quickly now either, it WAS there around summer 2014.  But put yourself in kernel's position if you're so short of memory you may fail to make progress or have to kill applications and some application mlocked a large region of apparently little used RAM which is backed by disk or could be paged out.  It's not the key point anyway, the questioner was confused about async non-blocking I/O and calls to mlock.  I really don't want to waste any more time on this.