# mlock() and Threading

Tags: linux, pthreads, openmp, mmap

Can mlock() be called safely from independently executing OpenMP or Posix threads, given that each thread is operating on a different region of virtual memory?  Does it create a systemwide synchronization barrier or force all threads to stall in some way?

I apologize if this is a duplicate; I was surprised when google searches for "mlock openmp"/"mlock thread safety" did not turn up the answer immediately.  Closest I could find was the second answer of [Non-blocking mlock()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939931/non-blocking-mlock), which seems to indicate that mlock() CAN be called from separate threads and does not enforce or require any synchronization barriers.

Comment: I don't see `mlock()` on the list of thread-unsafe functions here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html so presumably it should be safe.

Comment: Thanks!  Does that mean that mlock also does not cause implicit synchronization between threads?

Comment: No, `mlock()` is not on the list of async-safe functions here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html, so it *could* take a lock if it wanted. Such a lock would be a leaf-level lock and would thus not make the function thread-unsafe because it could not participate in deadlock.

Comment: So you're saying that yes, a call to mlock() in one thread could in principle cause other threads to stall at their calls to mlock(), until the first thread's call finishes?  basically im screwed, and i might as well use serial code?

Comment: _"... basically im screwed, and i might as well use serial code?"_ Is calling `mlock()` everything your OpenMP threads are doing?! Looks a bit like premature optimisation to me.

Comment: I suppose I will still get latency hiding if one thread operates on recently mlocked data while the other is in the process of mlocking.  But it wasn't the optimal, fully asynchronous behavior I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mlock()` is safe to call from multiple threads at once.

As to whether it synchronises against other calls to `mlock()`, it's a quality-of-implementation issue - in principle *any* system call could synchronise against any other, there's no text in POSIX that disallows it.  In practice you will often find that system calls that work on the process's memory map tend to contend with each other (so `mlock()` might not just contend with other `mlock()` calls but also `mmap()`).  You will need to test to see if contention is a actually a problem in your use case.